# Storing remember_token to a separate table than users?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

is it possible to set another table & column to store my remember tokens? I know that the framework tries to automatically find a `remember_token` column in my "users" model, but I want to store it separately from users. Is there a way to configure my default tokens table? Thank you

P.S - I'm using laravel 5

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to create separate model for storing remember tokens and define a relationship on your User model like so

```
public function rememberToken() {
    return $this->hasOne('RememberToken');
}
```

Then you need to override methods on your User model, originally defined in `Authenticatable` trait. Override `getRememberToken()` and `setRememberToken()` methods. You will also need to override `getRememberTokenName()` as it is used in `where` clause in `EloquentUserProvider::retrieveByToken()` see EloquentUserProvider line 60. In order for this to work properly you probably have to add global scope to your User model to join `remember_tokens` table on every query, and return `'remember_tokens.token'` from `getRememberTokenName()` method.

Think twice as it seems more trouble than it is worth. Why would you want to store your tokens separately anyway?

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer, It was not my decision I'm working for a project.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way Laravel works uses a seperate column in the users table to store a single remember_me token. From my understanding it seems that logging out resets this token regardless of storing the token in a cookie (correct me if I'm wrong).
https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/971
If you log in with remember_me checked on your personal computer,
then again on your phone,
and maybe again with any other device,
then finally the act of signing out on any device using the remember_me token or not will reset this token in the DB.

If Laravel had a separate table, able to remember each device, it might solve the problem.